# Node.js server sending info to ios app

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, backend, observer-pattern

I am new to backend programming but would like to try and put together the backend of an app I am building.  I essentially am looking to implement an observer type programming pattern, just between the server and ios app.  For instance two different app users may subscribe to different things on the node.js server and would get different json sent to the swift of the app to use.  I am unsure however how to go about trying to subscribe a user to the node.js using swift, and then essentially setting a listener for the json response as they come in.  I would appreciate any help on this sort of server programming pattern type work if anyone has any references or thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nodejs has the [Event Emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html), that can be an implementation of observer pattern.

In your case, you can use a special Event Emitter based class, the [Net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module, that is a event emitter to handle tcp connections. As TCP connections are bidirectional by default, you can handle events in both sides using it.

So, you could handle the calls from the swift app (or other languages). It's just open the socket with server and send/receive data.